# MapBox - Unable to resolve dependency 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0'

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using Mapbox ('com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0') but have an issue when implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0' in Android  Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1).

I had implementation :

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0'
```

}

and in settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
            username = "mapbox"
            password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
        }
    }
}
```

}

and it have issue when run build in build.gradle

- Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0.
- Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0.
- Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:10.2.0.

Comment: what's ur gradle version ?

Comment: it's grade 7.0.4